# Чи є український відповідник до слова "райдер"?

Tags: терміни, іншомовні-слова

Цікавить слово ***"райдер"*** чи існують відповідники в українській мові.

> ***[Райдер](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%83-%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81))*** - ( від англ. ride — поїздка, їхати) — список вимог, що пред'являються артистом (або групою) організаторам гастрольних
>   виступів. Фактично, це перерахування умов, яких потребують артисти до,
>   під час і після виступу. В українській мові є відповідник цього іншомовного слова — **виряд**

З СУМ-20

> **[ВИРЯД](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=210926&page=356)**  у, ч., заст. Одяг, обладунок і спорядження, перев.
>   військові.

На мою думку не зовсім підходить під визначення слова ***"райдер"***
Чи існують ще якісь відповідники до даного слова?

Comment: @follower виправила запитання.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Існують ще такі варіанти, які пропонують нам [тут](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/raider):

> **виможник, техлист**.

Однак з переглянутих мною сайтів, найбільшою популярністю користується саме виряд: [1](http://www.rejd.plast.org.ua/main/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4), [2](http://tabirreyd.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_21.html), [3](http://ua.convdocs.org/docs/index-79559.html) та ін.